# Django - How to do tuple unpacking in a template 'for' loop

Tags: python, django, templates, tuples, iterable-unpacking

In my views.py, I'm building a list of two-tuples, where the second item in the tuple is another list, like this:

```
[ Product_Type_1, [ product_1, product_2 ],
  Product_Type_2, [ product_3, product_4 ]]
```

In plain old Python, I could iteration the list like this:

```
for product_type, products in list:
    print product_type
    for product in products:
        print product
```

I can't seem to do the same thing in my Django template:

```
{% for product_type, products in product_list %}
    print product_type
    {% for product in products %}
        print product
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error from Django:

**Caught an exception while rendering: zip argument #2 must support iteration**

Of course, there is some HTML markup in the template, not print statements. Is tuple unpacking not supported in the Django template language? Or am I going about this the wrong way? All I am trying to do is display a simple hierarchy of objects - there are several product types, each with several products (in models.py, Product has a foreign key to Product_type, a simple one-to-many relationship).

Obviously, I am quite new to Django, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You talk about tuples, but your question contains only lists.  They are different things in python.

Comment: You actually don't have two-tuples.  Look carefully at your list, you have 4 list items. As Jonny Buchanan noted, you need to do this:

[ [Product_Type_1, [ product_1, product_2 ], ],
  [Product_Type_2, [ product_3, product_4 ], ], ]

to get a list version of two-tuples.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

it would be best if you construct your data like {note the '(' and ')' can be exchanged for '[' and ']' repectively, one being for tuples, one for lists}

```
[ (Product_Type_1, ( product_1, product_2 )),
   (Product_Type_2, ( product_3, product_4 )) ]
```

and have the template do this:

```
{% for product_type, products in product_type_list %}
    {{ product_type }}
    {% for product in products %}
        {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

the way tuples/lists are unpacked in for loops is based on the item returned by the list iterator.
each iteration only one item was returned. the first time around the loop, Product_Type_1, the second your list of products...

Comment: i.e. you thought you were building a list of two-tuples, but you forgot the tuple part - note the extra parentheses surrounding the product type/product list pairs in Cipher's answer

Comment: This does not work for older Django versions (like the one used in the GAE). Use Ashwin Rao's answer if you get this error: " 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed' "

Answer (score 106):

Another way is as follows.

If one has a list of tuples say:

```
mylst = [(a, b, c), (x, y, z), (l, m, n)]
```

then one can unpack this list in the template file in the following manner.
In my case I had a list of tuples which contained the URL, title, and summary of a document.

```
{% for item in mylst %}    
     {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1}} {{ item.2 }}    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `.0` ... not intuitive at all.

Comment: @iuliux trick is to remember that the template language makes `.` mean anything from variable access to subscription, going through method invocation, all with the same syntax... Still agree with you, tho :)

Comment: Why are the forward slashes \ there?

Answer (score 11):

You must used this way:

```
{% for product_type, products in product_list.items %}
    {{ product_type }}
    {% for product in products %}
       {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Don't forget the variable items in the dictionary data

Comment: Finally, the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed number in your tuples, you could just use indexing. I needed to mix a dictionary and the values were tuples, so I did this:

In the view:

```
my_dict = {'parrot': ('dead', 'stone'), 'lumberjack': ('sleep_all_night', 'work_all_day')}
```

In the template:

```
<select>
  {% for key, tuple in my_dict.items %}
    <option value="{{ key }}" important-attr="{{ tuple.0 }}">{{ tuple.1 }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just send the template a list of product types and do something like:

```
{% for product_type in product_type_list %}
    {{ product_type }}
    {% for product in product_type.products.all %}
        {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's been a little while so I can't remember exactly what the syntax is, let me know if that works.  Check the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Comment: Chris Lawlor hasn't explained how he's ended up with the data structure he has (which isn't actually list of two-tuples), but this suggested approach would result in N + 1 queries to display the product list.

Comment: Here be dragons.  Using this suggestion, you're making a separate trip to the database for each product_type.  I suspect that minimizing the database load is probably the motivation behind using tuples in the first place.

Comment: I think you could use select_related() to mitigate that particular concern, right?