# Is there a better way to iterate over tuples in a (Django) template in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to render `os.environ` in a template in [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). I believe the technology is (or is adapted from) the Django template engine version 0.96 (but correct me if I'm wrong).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271077/django-how-to-do-tuple-unpacking-in-a-template-for-loop) suggesting that you could do:

```
{{ for key, value in environ}}
```

But when I try that, I get an error saying:

> 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed': for key, value in environ

I guess that question was concerning another version of Django?

By the way, the value of `environ` is set to `os.environ.items()` before rendering the template.

Anyway, I came up a key_value_pair class that I could use instead:

```
class key_value_pair:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

def make_kvp(key, iter):
    return key_value_pair(key, iter[key])
```

`make_kvp` is small "factory" method that I later use to set the `environ` template value like this:

```
map(lambda x : make_kvp(x, os.environ), os.environ)
```

When doing that everything works just fine, but since I'm a totally new to the technologies in play here, I just wanted to make sure that I'm not overseeing some obvious simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over the sequence using a single name, then index the name to get at the individual elements.

Comment: With index you mean like `kvp[0]`? Because I tried that and its not working. But I guess my syntax is incorrect. I'm getting a `Could not parse the remainder: [0]` error.

Comment: You use periods in Django templates to index sequences. `kvp.0`

Comment: @klausbyskov: Use `.` in your template.  `kvp.0`.  The template language is not Python.  You might want to look at more of the Django tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. @S.Lott you are completely correct, I *do* have to read a lot more of the Django docs but I have been reading so many (other) docs today and I just wanted to get my feet wet with some coding. And I got stuck. Silly me, but I'm sure you know the feeling.

Comment: "I'm sure you know the feeling".  Sadly, no, I don't know that feeling.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in template you should write like this:

```
{% for x in dic %}

{% endfor %}
```